# count dictionary with multiple keys in iOS

Tags: ios, count, nsdictionary

This is my JSON :

```
collections =     {
        items =         (
                        {
                nom = "automne-hiver-2012-2013";
            },
                        {
                nom = carbon;
            },
                        {
                nom = colors;
            });
    };
}
```

I access to my json like this:

```
int j=0;
NSString *collections=self.dictionaryMenu[@"collections"][@"items"][j][@"nom"];
```

I'm looking for count all the key "nom" who are in my JSON.
I try :

```
for (objectKey in self.dictionaryMenu.allKeys) {
    count2 += [[self.dictionaryMenu objectForKey:objectKey] count];
               NSLog(@"Anzahl: %d", count2);
               }
               NSString *counter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"COUNT MENU (%d)", count2];
               NSLog(@"%@",counter);
```

Unfortunately, it sends me 1 ( i think that's because there is only 1 "collections" in the JSON).

How can i count all the key "nom" ?

Comment: By this do you mean the count of all items for which "nom" is non-nil?

Comment: Yes please, i would like the count of all items for which "nom" is non nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSArray *items = self.dictionaryMenu[@"collections"][@"items"];
NSUInteger count = 0;
for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
    if (item[@"nom"]) {
        count++;
    }
}
```